# Windows: Unable to find "grunt.js" config file

Tags: npm, gruntjs

Under Windows, I am getting the following error when I run grunt on my project:

Unable to find "grunt.js" config file. Do you need any --help?

I have exactly the same configuration as my mac and its failing - anyone seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix this:

Uninstalled grunt globally:

```
npm uninstall -g grunt
```

Installed grunt-cli globally:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Then, in project root dir:

```
npm install
```

And all is good.   Hope this works for anyone else running into this.